# Deploying SSRS reports on an "Air Gapped" report server without SSDT?

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2012

Whats the simplest way to deploy multiple reports (.rdl) along with the respective data sources to a machine which cannot be connected to from Visual Studio?

I can only place files at a given location, connect to the report server via remote desktop and execute them. I am not permitted to open firewall ports, or establish any other sort of connectivity between my machine and the report server.

One way is to manually upload the files one at a time, which I wish to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [RS.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx) script. This would allow you to create a script, a batch file and a set of .rdl files.
Then you just call rs.exe with the script you created to upload the files to the report server.

You can find an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531017.aspx)

There is also a tool called `rsscripter.exe` created Jasper Smith, a SQL Server MVP.
Apparently it is now included in [finebuild](https://github.com/SQL-FineBuild/SQL-FineBuild/wiki) and the zip is still [archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20120830141644/http://www.sqldbatips.com/samples/code/RSScripter/RSScripter.zip). See [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120830141644/http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62) for the original article.